# How to create SharePoint list with custom template using Managed Client Object Model?

Tags: list, client-object-model, custom-list, list-template

Creating lists in SharePoint using Managed Client Object Model is rather easy task. Here's how to create a list with SharePoint's custom list template:

```
ListCreationInformation lci;
List list;

lci = new ListCreationInformation();
lci.Title = title;
lci.Description = description;
lci.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.GenericList;
list = clientContext.Web.Lists.Add(lci);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

But what happens if I don't what to use any of the default `ListTemplateType` templates? What if I have created my own list template and I want to use it in the code to create lists based on it? Please help, thanks.

Comment: I can't comment due to my low rep, but I'd like to know if you ever figured this out. I have looked long and hard for a solution and am yet to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the `TemplateFeatureId` property *looks* like it should do what we want, ie. create a list from a given template, but it doesn't.

On [this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c018867b-d8c3-438a-b3f9-959b6d42fbcc/create-list-using-custom-template-using-the-client-object-model?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) and [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/4c22ced6-0bf2-485a-b0fa-0a2aea3a5a30/how-to-use-customschemaxml-to-create-list-in-csom?forum=sharepointdevelopment), on MSDN forums, the accepted answer is that you can't create a list from a list template at all using the client side object model - and that's my experience, too.

Comment: Can this be achieved using REST? If not does it mean that using client side scripting we cannot create lists using list templates?

Answer (score 4):

I cannot test this because I dont have a dev environment at the moment, but the following should work:

```
ListCreationInformation lci;
List list;

lci = new ListCreationInformation();
lci.Title = title;
lci.Description = description;


ListTemplate lt = ClientContext.Current.Web.ListTemplates.First(z => z.Name == "MyTemplateName");
lci.TemplateFeatureId = lt.FeatureId;

list = clientContext.Web.Lists.Add(lci);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listcreationinformation_members.aspx

> TemplateFeatureId = Gets or sets a value that specifies the feature
>   identifier of the feature that contains the list schema for the new
>   list.

Comment: Anyone reading this: don't get your hopes up. It only works for built-in list templates, not custom ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get custom templates you have to use context.Site.GetCustomListTemplates() instead of context.Web.ListTemplates

```
public static ListTemplate GetCustomSiteTemplate(ClientContext ctx, string templateName)
{
    var site = ctx.Site;
    ctx.Load(site);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    ListTemplateCollection ltc = site.GetCustomListTemplates(ctx.Web);
    ctx.Load(ltc);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    var listTemplate = ltc.FirstOrDefault(lt => lt.Name == templateName);
    return listTemplate;
}
```

On SharePoint 2013, I found my template and used it in ListCreationInformation, the list was created but it didn't have the settings of the template (views etc even though it contained them).

According to [this discussion on SharePoint 2010](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c018867b-d8c3-438a-b3f9-959b6d42fbcc/create-list-using-custom-template-using-the-client-object-model?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious):

*"You cannot create list using the custom template using Client OM. Instead, you can create a custom list definition,  and then create list based on this definition.
[More information about Create List using Client Object Model](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/11/01/using-the-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-part-4.aspx)"*